# Is it possible to group stacked bar graph in angular charts

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

I've created plunkr for stacked bar graph, is it possible to have multiple stacks for same label ?

Comment: My plnkr. https://plnkr.co/edit/7ZhucDiBC0ufMof3iAWd

Comment: @Ullas do you want like 2 stacks labeled as monday or something

Comment: Correct 2 stacks labeled as Monday, so 2 stack towers for Monday

Comment: then change the labels array   `$scope.labels = ['Monday', 'Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];`

Comment: Actually it's for different data sets... Two stacks will have different values for Monday example stack 1 2015=65,2016=28, stack 2 2015=70,2016=44,

Comment: I have seen is possible on chart.js 2.x version but how to do in angular charts I'm bit lost

Comment: are u looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/4rjge8sk/

Comment: Yes correct sachila

Comment: Hi is it possible any suggestions